# JTree inside JScrollPane inside JPanel inside JSplitPane

Tags: java, swing, layout, jscrollpane, jmenu

I am designing a swing java program, which has many "regions" in its window. All regions are first put inside  a (chain of) `JSplitPanes` in order to be fully resizable. One of such elements is a `JTree`, that I have put within a `JScrollPane` since its size must be dynamically changed. So the current order is:

- (1) a `JSplitPane` (region) containing...
- (2) a `JScrolPane` containing...
- (3) a `JTree`

As it is now, when the user resizes (1), the content in (2) and (3) automatically adapts to cover the whole region, as I want." (it works fine).

Now I'd like to put a toolbar (`JPanel` "A" with fixed preferred size) in the same "region", right above the `JScrollPane`. So I made a `JPanel` "B", and added both (A) and (2) to it.
My problem is that now, when I resize (1), the content in (2) does not automatically adapt its size to the whole region space left free (that is the whole "region" minus the fixed space required by (A) ). In this new condition I have:

- (1) a `JSplitPane` (region) containing...
- (B) `JPanel` B containing...
- (2) a `JScrolPane` containing...
- (3) a `JTree`
- (B) also contanins JPanel (A)

what should I do to get the size of (2) automatically link to the size of the region (=  1), as it used to be before?
I tried with several layout managers for (B) without success.
Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: I have no idea what a `JScrollField` is. That is not a standard Swing component. Use a proper layout manager or nested layout managers. I would suggest a BorderLayout. Add one component to the BorderLayout.PAGE_START and the other to BorderLayout.CENTER. Post an [mcve] if you need more help.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.
My mistake, I wrote `JscrollField` instead f `JScrollPane`, sorry for that, I've edited that mistake.

I did try with BorderLayout: the `JTree` was put in the centre of the "region", but if I reduced the size of the region (acting on the `JSplitPane`) it never got the scroll bars. So its rendering size was not linked to that of the "region".

I will indeed try to build a small example, as you suggested, yet it is quite complex, due to the size of the project I am dealing with.

Comment: `yet it is quite complex, due to the size of the project I am dealing with` - it has nothing to do with your project. All you need is a panel with a BorderLayout and two components added to the panel. Then you add the panel to the split pane and a label to the split pane. The point of the `MCVE` is to test the concept with minimal code. In fact first try it with a JTextArea, instead of a JTree. Get that working to prove the concept. Then try the JTree, it should work the same.